# Xamarin forms date picker binding date and doing something when the date changes

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin.forms, datepicker

So I have this in my xaml page:

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="Date" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Format="D" Date="{Binding SelectedDate}"  />
```

And in my view model I have:

```
 private DateTime selectedDate;
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedDate = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedDate"));
            
        }
    }
```

I wanted to do something with the date when it changes. I have a function in my view model:

```
DoSomething(){//i do something when the user changes the date}
```

Can I call it like this, after the date changes:

```
 private DateTime selectedDate;
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedDate = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedDate"));
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course you could invoke it in the set method . You could add a if statement  to avoid calling `DoSomething();` when select the same date . `if(selectedDate != value){ selectedDate = value; //...}`

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms DatePicker has DateSelected property.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="myDatePicker"Format="D" DateSelected="OnDateSelected" Date="{Binding SelectedDate}"  />

 void OnDateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs args)
 {
        DoSomething();
 }
```

For more details, see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker

Comment: Yes , I know this, but I want to do the functionality in my view model. The method OnDateSelected will be in the .xaml.cs file. I don't want it there. I need it in my view model.

Comment: @Candyfloss Hi, actually it will be invoked in `.xaml.cs`, and you also can invoke `OnDateSelected` method to change model data.